# Jquery - POST request turns out to be a GET request.. how come?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I never had such a problem and I'm pretty puzzled:

```
function delete_post(id) {
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your post? (this action cannot be undone)")

  if (answer) {
    $.ajax({ 
      method:"post",
      url: "ajax/delete.php",
      data:"id="+id,
      beforeSend: function(){ $('#delete_post').show('slow'); },
      success: function(html) { $("#delete_post").html(html); }
    });
  }
  else {}
  return false;
}
```

I had a problem on the server side and, after analizing the output with firebug I noticed that the request turns out to be a GET instead of a post! What Am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh easy one. The property is type not method:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type:"POST",
  url: "ajax/delete.php",
  data:"id="+id,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#delete_post').show('slow');
  },
  success: function(html) {
    $("#delete_post").html(html);
  }
});
```

**Note:** from the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) the method (type) is in uppercase ('GET', 'POST'). I don't actually know if it matters or not however.